# textColor in slices of jqplot pieChart

Tags: jqplot, pie-chart

I'm trying do change the textColor of jqplot pieCharts to #ffffff, because a dark slice is eating its label.
I didn't found a way to do that. Any ideas?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override the CSS

HTML

```
<div id="pieChart"></div>
```

CSS

```
#pieChart{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NYewy/247/)